# ignite: what is the weekly time series query?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

```
select year(date), week(date), sum(bottles_sold)
from LIQUORS_SALES
group by year(date), week(date)
order by year(date), week (date).
```

above one is the query i used to fetch weekly time series for sum of bottles_sold. But i am getting wrong number of bottles sold in every year first week.

what i observed is sum of bottles sold in additional days of every year are adding to first week of that year.

Ex:- take 2012 which is leap year (366 days) where my first week starts from jan 1st. i have a sales of bottles on 2012-01(1-7 days) week are 200, 2012 - 52 (358-364 days) are 500, now sales in last two days (365th and 366th) are 150 which should actually add to 2013-01 week, but it's adding to 2012-01 where my 2012-01 bottles sold become 350.

how can i fix it? is there anything miss in the sql query i used ? or is there anything i need to change the configurations in grid-gain or something wrong with the ignite database itself?

please help me to fix this, it cause a serious problem to do time series analysis. let me know if you need more information about the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2012-53 week belongs to 2012 year. If you want another behavior, you should add a custom column which is an expression that returns the wanted year for a given week.

Comment: Is it a MySQL question or Apache Ignite question?

Comment: @alamar, it's a Apache Ignite question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop grouping by `year(date), week(date)` and start instead grouping by `iso_year(date), iso_week(date)`.

```
 select iso_year(date), iso_week(date), sum(bottles_sold) from LIQUORS_SALES group by iso_year(date), iso_week(date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alamar. it's working , i'm getting correct time series. Thanks